# Generate SVG from dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, svg

Is there a way to save text from a dynamic text field into some kind of SVG format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do. [SVG text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) is quite straight forward:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="20" y="20" font-family="Arial">Hello World!</text>
</svg>
```

So you can fetch the text from the input field and just feed it into an SVG template.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read up on the documentation you linked to.

Comment: You're welcome. I like the SVG specification really well. It's good written and both informative and easy to understand. Therefore I'd like to encourage you to read more of it.